# Kubuntu and PDA net Bluetooth DUN

Tags: 13.04, networking, kubuntu, bluetooth

I cannot find information regarding how to setup Bluetooth DUN using PDA net on my Samsung Galaxy S4 (AT&T) for Kubuntu 13.04 x86_64. I just need a definitive answer and I'm pretty good with Linux but I'm still learning. Also on a side not what is a great website to learn more about Linux and the commands and structure of the file system. I hate windows I only use Linux now and I want to know as much about Linux as I do windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please limit your posts to one question. The answer to your second question (learn Linux, commands, and filesystem structure) are answered all around this site; just use the [Ask Ubuntu search](http://askubuntu.com/search). So please, remove that second question from your post. You can edit your post by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath the text of your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Blueman Bluetooth manager. You can get it from software center or to install it from the terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Comment: I did install it and I can connect the device undera serial port rfcomm0 and I tried using KPPP to use as a dial up and it doesn't work.